# windows 7, no adhoc option

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

Trying to share my cable connection with some wireless only devices.

Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1.

A wired and a Wireless network cards.

Connected via the Wired.

There is no option to create an adHoc network.

This is a IT managed machine, so it may be disabled. but microsoft or my company IT grunts knows nothing about it.

[image]

[image]

any ideas if it is disabled by IT or if i'm just missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C684JFKtwyw) may be it will be helpfull.

Comment: summary of the video: you have to enable your wireless device.  Mine is already enabled. thanks. upvotnig as it might be a solution for someone else. but for me, as you can see on the device manager scree nshot, it was already enabled.